# Masking Text while scanning - C

Tags: c

I have to prompt user for a password, so when entering the password I want the characters to be masked, I have created this code where characters are masked until enter key is pressed. But the character array pwd is not reading the characters i guess!

```
char pwd[10];
while(ch!=13)
{
     pwd[i] = ch;
     ch = '*' ;
     printf("%c",ch);
     ch=getch();
     i++;
}
pwd[i]='\0';
printf("%s",pwd);
```

Nothing is printed when I try to print pwd.

Comment: This is os and terminal dependenter. Curses library for unix

Comment: Is `i` initialized somewhere?

Comment: Reading a password yourself might create a security-hole. You might think of using the operation system services for this (PAM on Linux and whatever Windows provides). This has many additional advantages like using alternative authenfication automatically, etc.

Comment: @Olaf: while you're absolutely correct,  pretty sure this is for a school assignment.  There's no way this is for real software.

Comment: @rost0031 Why not? Beginners are very ambitious sometimes..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: please don't scare me like that.

Comment: @rost0031: That's what I assumed, but OTOH it cannot harm to place the seed of awareness into an ambitious mind :-)

Comment: @rost0031 Well, if you spend enough time on SO you can notice some questions like "I know how to add `a` and `b`. So how can I write the Doom 3 game now?" (not related to the OP by any means)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: yeah, I've definitely seen some of those.  This didn't have quite the same feel to it.

Comment: Show all of your code.  ch is missing at a minimum

Comment: what happens if the password is larger than 9 characters?

Comment: I know there are a lot of better ways to do passwords but This is for a school assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define MAX_PW_LENGTH 12

char pwd[MAX_PW_LENGTH + 1];

/** Get Password
 *
 *  \return True on success, false on failure (EOF, too long).
 */
bool getPwd(void)
{
    size_t idx;
    char ch;
    for ( idx = 0 ; idx < sizeof(pwd) - 1 ; idx++ ) {
        ch = getchar();
        if ( (ch == EOF) || (ch == '\n') || (ch == '\r') )
            break;
        pwd[i] = ch;
    }
    pwd[i] = `\0`;
    return (ch == `\r`) || (ch == '\n');  // might depend on OS what return-key yields
}
```

Note I used [getchar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) as getch is non-standard and (IIRC) does not wait for input, but returns instantly (non-blocking). Oh, and I actually **do** not output anything as getchar requires the whole line to be entered first (buffered - see below). problem is: the console echoes chars as being typed by default (also: see below). So, you need non-echo input; the rest will do fine.

Ok, I tried to provide a simple solution. However, for Linux at least, `getchar()` has two major disadvantages by default: the terminal echoes by default all input, so the password is shown while typing. Second, it buffers the input line before it is returned char-by-char in getchar().

The first is obviously a killer-antifeature, while the second only prohibits echoing stars or similar (which I discourage to do anyway). However, both features of a console can be disabled using termios; just google for this.

An alternative would be to use ncurses which provides getch() and a simple 'noecho()' call to disable this behaviour (and cbreak() to disable buffering). However, that seems to require using the TUI-features and is not possible to be used like normal console-input (but still simpler than termios).

Conclusion: use the system's functions to get a password/authenticate. As if had not known this already:-)

Here is a ncurses version:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

bool getPwd(void)
{
    // this should be done in main() or so only once
      initscr(); noecho(); cbreak();

    size_t idx;
    char ch;
    for ( idx = 0 ; idx < sizeof(pwd) - 1 ; idx++ ) {

        // wait for input
        while ( ERR == (ch = getch()) )  ;
        if ( ch == '\n' )
            break;
              addch('*');     // this should actually be disabled
        pwd[i] = ch;
    }
    pwd[i] = `\0`;
    return ch == '\n';  // might depend on OS what return-key yields
}
}
```

Case closed.

Comment: Fine, yours is better.  I was trying to keep mine as similar to OP's as possible to help him understand what's happening.  But sure, go and show me up :)

Comment: @rost0031: Still having problems (stupid me!): this only works propperly without output as getchar still requires EOF/return and does not return each char as typed. Trying to use getch() now, but this requires (n)curses and I can't get it to link. Funny, never programmed C on Linux; just on embedded and Python on Linux. Might have to open my first question. Irony? :-))

Comment: Speaking of irony, what were you saying earlier about all the extra edits...?

Comment: Nothing said! *whistle* (Hey, I actually was willing to wait before voting. So do me the same favour:-)

Comment: I voted you up.  As I said, it's still a better solution than mine.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, now I can't get it out of my head until I get this code to build properly :-}. At least it reminds me why I hate using C on a PC.

Comment: Got it finally running with ncurses. Hmm... never used before, but seems to be quite easy to use. Niiice!

Answer (score 0):

As @Olaf and @EugeneSh. mentioned, this is a TERRIBLE way to do passwords.  That said, here's some help.

Assuming i is being initialized somewhere, move "pwd[i] = ch" to the end of your loop but before "i++"
The whole thing should look something like this (note that this is still very wrong):

```
char pwd[10];
while(ch!=13)
{
     ch = '*' ;
     printf("%c",ch);
     ch=getch();
     pwd[i] = ch;
     i++;
}
pwd[i]='\0';
printf("%s",pwd);
```

I would actually probably print the "*" only after the user enters their character.  Let's fix the other problems while we're at it.

```
int i = 0;    /* Since you didn't specify if this was initialized */
char pwd[15]; /* Setting this to 10 would have caused you to overrun your
                buffer.  Not only is that crashy, it's a also a HUGE 
                source of security holes.  Let's not do that. */
/* Unless you're waiting for a user to enter in a 
   character which happens to be ASCII 13, you'll 
   never get out.  Let's just change that to i since 
   I'm guessing you want a 13 character password. */
while(i != 13)  
{
     char ch=getch();
     pwd[i++] = ch; /* You can post increment right here so you don't 
                     have to do it at the end of the loop where you 
                     might forget */
     printf("*");
     fflush(stdout);  /* Since we are using printf to a stdout (not 
                         stderr, we need to manually flush stdout or 
                         things won't show up until a newline is 
                         eventually printed. */
}
printf("\n"); /* Print a newline so we don't end up printing the 
                 password on the same line */

pwd[14]='\0';
printf("Password entered into our crappy security system: %s",pwd);
```

Comment: The problem is terminal specific (whether it's a tui or a gui)

Comment: Actually printing any marker for a password should be banned. This originated from Windows (no baching); Unix/Linux did not echo anything, so one cannot even guess the length of a password from the number of symbols output. Sadly enough Linux/Unix desktops have adopted this missbehaviour (for KDE at least it acn be disabled).

Comment: The code contains a buffer overflow and cannot be terminated by EOF and/or CR,.

Comment: Yep, I just fixed that a second ago.

Comment: I'll have a look at the final version then, before I think of voting;-) *getting some popcorn*

Comment: @Olaf:  :P Fair enough.

Comment: Just tell me. (sorry, feeling a bit foolish today).

Comment: Nah, think I'll just keep editing this until it's downvoted into oblivion forcing me to delete it.  But seriously, I keep finding really dumb mistakes and I'm having a difficult time blaming the OP since hey, he doesn't know any better.  I should.

Comment: Fine for me. Nothing interesting on TV:-))